# In Azure I have no Resource Groups, but it says that I have 'Insufficient number of vCPUs'

Tags: azure, azure-vm, vcpu, azure-aks

In azure I created two AKS clusters, then deleted them and now I want to create another one with B2s VM size, but it says that I have insufficient number of vCPUs, I deleted all the resource groups and I ran in console 'az vm list-usage --location "" -o table' command, "Total Regional vCPUs" value was 0, but it still says the same.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello @RubenAlexanyan, May i know if its the same for other regions as well ? can you try some other region instead of East_US?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misinterpret the error. You have not hit max CPU count usage. The message clearly says you need *at least 4 vCpus*.

It is interesting, but unclear, even though the [documentation](https://aka.ms/aks-vm-sizes) says minimum 2 vCpu required, somehow the portal now does not seem to allow those sizes and makes you go for a higher vCpu count.

To bypass, create cluster using Azure CLI:

```
az aks create -g so -n mycluster --node-vm-size standard_b2s -c 1
```